# EC2 Instance took too long to respond

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2

I have a web server that I am running. I am attempting to load the test page by visiting the public DNS of the EC2 Instance. I keep getting the error that the instance "took too long to respond."

My security groups allow listening on ports 22 and 80.

When I add the port 443 the error changes to "refused to connect".

I ensured by running the `service httpd status` that the web service was active:

```
[ec2-user@ip-redacted ~]$ service httpd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
             └─php-fpm.conf
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-06-18 05:05:28 UTC; 41min ago
       Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
   Main PID: 30282 (httpd)
     Status: "Total requests: 16; Idle/Busy workers 100/0;Requests/sec: 0.00645; Bytes served/sec:   3 B/sec"
      Tasks: 177 (limit: 1114)
     Memory: 18.3M
        CPU: 1.202s
     CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
             ├─30282 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             ├─30343 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             ├─30347 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             ├─30348 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             └─30350 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Jun 18 05:05:28 ip-redacted.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Starting httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 18 05:05:28 ip-redacted.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Started httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server.
Jun 18 05:05:28 ip-redacted.ec2.internal httpd[30282]: Server configured, listening on: port 80
```

I ran `curl -v http://localhost` and received:

```
[ec2-user@ip-redacted ~]$ curl -v http://localhost
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Sun, 18 Jun 2023 05:38:49 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.56 (Amazon Linux)
< Last-Modified: Mon, 11 Jun 2007 18:53:14 GMT
< ETag: "2d-432a5e4a73a80"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 45
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I'd like to have the test page pop up when I visit the public DNS.

Comment: Why do you use port 443? Its clear you haven't setup any SSL on the instance nor  your web server is listening on port 443.

Comment: Your Browser might default to try https first (thus the long time and immediate error when you open 443) or the domain might come preloaded with HSTS (e.g. `.dev` domains _can not_ be accessed through http, they _must_ be on https)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you `curl -v http://localhost` returned the correct HTTP response shows that Apache was installed correctly and is listening on port 80. However, the `took too long to respond` message indicates that your security group is not configured properly. Ensure that your security group has an inbound rule for HTTP port 80 and that the source is `0.0.0.0/0` for ipv4 and if you want to accept ipv6 requests then you will also need another rule for HTTP on port 80 and source is `::/0` as per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html#sg-rules-web-server).

In the aws console your ipv4 inbound rule will look something like this:

[image: ipv4 port 80]

Comment: I have that. It turns out that it doesn't work on Chrome when I have many tabs open. Not sure why.